# RxJS - receiving data in batches of time + max

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I'm playing with RxJS for the first time, and I'm trying to create a simple observable that will take both a maximum number of entries *and* wait for a time interval to pass before passing the data on to subscribers.

This is what I have:

```js
import EventEmitter from "events";

import { fromEvent } from "rxjs";
import { bufferTime, filter, take } from "rxjs/operators";

const ev = new EventEmitter();
const observer = fromEvent(ev, "log").pipe(
  take(10),
  bufferTime(1000),
  filter(logs => !!logs.length)
);

observer.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(`received: ${data.length}`);
});

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  ev.emit("log", { hello: "world" });
}
```

**What I expected to happen:**

`received: 10` to be printed 10x, at 1 second intervals.

**What actually happened:**

`received: 10` was printed once, and then the script exits.

**Why I *think* it's happening**

I'm new to RxJS, but from what I can gather the `take()` operator emits a 'completed' status after it has taken 10 entries, which prevents any further subscriptions from firing.

How do I make this observable 'recurring' so that it'll a) take a maximum of 10, b) ensure it runs, at most, once every 1000ms, and c) repeat forever?

Comment: unfortunately cannot give your a solution for your problem, but you may have a look at `bufferCount` and `bufferTime`

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/buffercount.html
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/buffertime.html

Comment: @OleksandrFedotov - thanks. I'm already (attempting to) use `bufferTime` in my example code, and `bufferCount` looks like it _waits_ until the buffer is full, which is not what I want. I just want to take a maximum of 10 _and_ run - at most - once per second... then repeat ad infinitum.

Comment: maybe the expand operator can help here for the recursion: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/expand.html

Comment: @RenéWinkler - could you point to any examples of how `expand` might apply in this case, please?

Answer (score 2):

After reading your last comment, a way to consider to solve the problem could be to combine `bufferTime` with `interval` using `zip`.

Basically the idea is that you can set a rhythm of notifications using `interval` - for instance you set `interval(1000)` to have an Observable that emits every second.

Then you can use `bufferTime(1000, null, 10)` to make sure that you emit an array every 1 second or if your buffer reaches 10 items, whichever comes first.

Now if you `zip` these 2 Observables you obtain an Observable which emits every second, because of `interval(1000)`, and it emits also whatever comes out of `bufferTime(1000, 0, 10)` in sequence. So, if the source Observable emits more than 10 items in a second, the first 10 will be emitted in the first notification, the others will remain buffered in the Observable and will be emitted in the subsequent notifications in chunks of 10 every second.

The code probably makes this clearer.

```
const ev = new EventEmitter();
// I merge to the event stream created by 'ev' a single notification emitted after 5 seconds, 
// just to make the thing a bit more complex
const sourceObs = merge(
  fromEvent(ev, "log"),
  of(1).pipe(delay(5000))
)

function simpleObservable(maxEntries: number, waitTime: number) {
  return zip(
    timer(0, waitTime),
    sourceObs.pipe(
      bufferTime(waitTime, null, maxEntries),
    )
  )
  .pipe(
    filter(logs => !!logs[1].length),
    map(logs => logs[1])
  )
}

const maxEntries = 4;
const waitTime = 1000;
simpleObservable(maxEntries, waitTime)
.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(`received: ${data.length}`);
});

for (let i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
  ev.emit("log", { hello: "world " + i + 'A' });
}
// some other events are fired after 8 seconds, to make the source more complex
setTimeout(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
    ev.emit("log", { hello: "world " + i + 'B' });
  }
}, 8000);
```

Clearly you need to consider that, if the source Observable emits at an speed higher than your ability to consume notifications, you may end up with memory problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert a simple `tap(d => console.log(JSON.stringify(d))),` operator before `take(10)` and after `bufferTime` and you see what happens.

Basically you have a loop that emits 100 events. Out of this loop you create an Observable which notifies 100 times the object emitted by you event loop.

This whole thing happens **synchronously** in your example.

Then the Observable is transformed by a pipe which does the following:

- first takes just the first 10 notifications via the `take` operator
- then says "accumulate all the notifications which happen in the first
  1 second and emit them in form of an array" - considering that the
  whole emission process is synchronous and that you take the first 10
  of them, then `bufferTime(1000)` will emit one array of 10 items
  after 1 second
- nothing else will be emitted by this stream, since `take(10)`
  completes the source Observable after 10 synchronous notifications,
  so the `filter` operator is of no use
- last, in the subscription you receive just 1 notification, i.e. the only one emitted by `bufferTime`

Said that, probably what you want to achieve can be accomplished by code along these lines

```
const ev = new EventEmitter();

function simpleObservable(maxEntries: number, waitTime: number) {
  return fromEvent(ev, "log").pipe(
    bufferCount(maxEntries),
    filter(logs => !!logs.length),
    mergeMap(logs => of(logs).pipe(delay(waitTime)), 1),
  )
}

simpleObservable(10, 1000)
.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(`received: ${data.length}`);
});

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  ev.emit("log", { hello: "world" });
}
```

The key here is that first you slice the stream of events into arrays of 10 events each, and this is done via the `bufferCount` operator.

Then you introduce the asynchronicity using `mergeMap` with concurrency level set to 1 (which is equivalent to the operator `concatMap`). You basically transform each array emitted by `bufferCount` into another Observable via the `of` function and apply a delay of 1 second to each of the new Observables. Then you concatenate them so that they are emitted each after the other with the time difference of 1 second.

**UPDATED RESPONSE after @Lee Benson comment**

`bufferTime` can be the answer to your problem.

`bufferTime` has 3 parameters:

- ***bufferTimeSpan***: specifies the lifespan of the buffer, i.e. the Observable emits the buffer and resets it after at each interval
  specified by ***bufferTimeSpan***
- ***bufferCreationInterval***: to be left `null` for our purpose
- ***maxBufferSize***: specifies the max size of the buffer - if the size is reached, then the Observable emits the buffer and resets it

So, if we use the first and the last parameter we should be able to reach the desired objectives.

This is the test I have put together

```
const ev = new EventEmitter();
// I merge to the event stream created by 'ev' a single notification emitted after 5 seconds, 
// just to make the thing a bit more complex
const sourceObs = merge(
  fromEvent(ev, "log"),
  of(1).pipe(delay(5000))
)

function simpleObservable(maxEntries: number, waitTime: number) {
  return sourceObs.pipe(
    bufferTime(waitTime, null, maxEntries),
    filter(logs => !!logs.length),
  )
}

simpleObservable(10, 2000)
.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(`received: ${data.length}`);
});

for (let i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
  ev.emit("log", { hello: "world" });
}
// some other events are fired after 6 seconds, to make the source more complex
setTimeout(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
    ev.emit("log", { hello: "world" });
  }
}, 6000);
```

Comment: thanks. The issue I with `bufferCount` is that it's waiting _until_ there's 10 items, and not firing if there's fewer. I'm trying to build a queue that will invoke `.subscribe()` whenever there's _at least_ 1 result _and_ at least 1 second has passed, in batches of a maximum of 10 per time.

Comment: If I look at your example, you are emitting synchronously 100 events. What is the behavior expected in this case? Do you want to invoke `subscribe` 10 times, each time with an array of 10 notifications, with an interval of 1 seconds each? Do you expect the 10 notifications to be given to `subscribe` as fast as possible?

Comment: thanks, that's closer, but still not quite there. If we change `maxEntries` to 4 and leave `waitTime` at 1000, we get 4x "Received: 4" messages back in the console after 1s, rather than each message buffered at 1s intervals. Another example: Change the loop to emit 28 events instead of 19; we'll get "Received: 10" _twice_ after 1000ms, followed by a final "Received: 8". What _should_ happen is "Received: 10" after 1s, "Received: 10" after 2s, "Received: 8" after 3s.

Comment: Looking at `bufferTime` some more, it seems like it emits when _either_ the time has been exhausted, _or_ the buffer has been reached - whichever is first. Hence in your example, "Received: 10" is printed immediately, followed by a 1000ms pause, then "Received: 9". What I'm trying to achieve is for the buffer time to be awaited _always_, and then as a _secondary_ criteria, to not exceed `maxEntries`. Any extra entries should be buffered in the _next_ iteration of bufferTime.